# why mvn clean verify is running surefire plugin only

Tags: java, maven, maven-surefire-plugin, serenity-bdd, maven-failsafe-plugin

My project structure is:

```
Project_Name

|-src/main/java

|-src/test/java

    |-default package

        |-MyIT.java

    |-steps

        |-MySteps.java

|-pom.xml
```

MyIT.java:

```
@RunWith(SerenityRunner.class)
public class MyIT {
    
    @Steps
    MySteps mySteps;
    
    
    @BeforeClass
    public static void setUp() {
    RestAssured.baseURI="https://restcountries.com/";
    System.out.println("1");
    }
    
    
    @Test
    @Title("Check \"Republic Of India\"")
    public void verify_that_given_string_found_in_the_response() {
    
    
        
          mySteps.whenIOpenURLForIndia(); 
          mySteps.thenRepublicOfIndiaFoundInResponse();
    }
}
```

MySteps.java:

```
public class MySteps {

    
    @Step("When I Open the URL for India")
    public void whenIOpenURLForIndia() {
        SerenityRest.given().relaxedHTTPSValidation().basePath("v2/name/{country}").pathParam("country", "INDIA").when().get();
    }
    
    @Step("Then \"Republic of India\" found in the response")
    public void thenRepublicOfIndiaFoundInResponse() {
        
        SerenityRest.lastResponse().then().body("[1].altSpellings",hasItem("Republic of India"));
    }
}
```

Pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>org.restcountries</groupId>
  <artifactId>Serenity_RestAssured_Assignment1</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  
  <name>Serenity_RestAssured_Assignment1</name>
  <!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
  <url>http://www.example.com</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
   
  </properties>


     <dependencies>
            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.serenity-bdd/serenity-core -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>net.serenity-bdd</groupId>
                <artifactId>serenity-core</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.15</version>
            </dependency>

            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.serenity-bdd/serenity-junit -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>net.serenity-bdd</groupId>
                <artifactId>serenity-junit</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.15</version>
            </dependency>

            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.serenity-bdd/serenity-rest-assured -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>net.serenity-bdd</groupId>
                <artifactId>serenity-rest-assured</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.15</version>
            </dependency>

            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>junit</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                <version>4.13.2</version>
                
            </dependency>

            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.rest-assured/rest-assured -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
                <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
                <version>4.4.0</version>
                
            </dependency>
            
            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hamcrest/java-hamcrest -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
                <artifactId>java-hamcrest</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.0.0</version>
                
            </dependency>
            
            

  </dependencies>

 <build>
    
    <pluginManagement>
                    <plugins>
                        <plugin>
                            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                            <version>3.8.1</version>
                            <configuration>
                                <source>1.8</source>
                                <target>1.8</target>
                            </configuration>
                        </plugin>
                        <plugin>
                            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                            <version>3.0.0-M4</version>
                            <configuration>
                                <skip>true</skip>
                                
                            </configuration>
                        </plugin>
                        <plugin>
                            <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                            <version>3.0.0-M4</version>
                            <configuration>
                                <skipTests>false</skipTests>
                            </configuration>
                            <executions>
                                <execution>

                                    <goals>
                                        <goal>integration-test</goal>
                                        <goal>verify</goal>
                                    </goals>
                                </execution>
                            </executions>
                        </plugin>

                    </plugins>
                    
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
  



</project>
```

Now when I run it using:

```
mvn clean verify
```

its output is:

```
    [INFO] Scanning for projects...
    [INFO]
    [INFO] ---------< org.restcountries:Serenity_RestAssured_Assignment1 >---------
    [INFO] Building Serenity_RestAssured_Assignment1 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
    [INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
    [INFO]
    [INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ Serenity_RestAssured_Assignment1 ---
    [INFO] Deleting C:\ eclipse_workspace\Serenity_RestAssured_Assignment1\target
    [INFO]
    [INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ Serenity_RestAssured_Assignment1 ---
    [INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
    [INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory 
C:\ eclipse_workspace\Serenity_RestAssured_Assignment1\src\main\resources
    [INFO]
    [INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) @ Serenity_RestAssured_Assignment1 ---
    [INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
    [INFO]
    [INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ Serenity_RestAssured_Assignment1 ---
    [INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
    [INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory 
    C:\ eclipse_workspace\Serenity_RestAssured_Assignment1\src\test\resources
    [INFO]
    [INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ Serenity_RestAssured_Assignment1 ---
    [INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
    [INFO] Compiling 2 source files to 
    C:\ eclipse_workspace\Serenity_RestAssured_Assignment1\target\test-classes
    [INFO]
    [INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0-M4:test (default-test) @ Serenity_RestAssured_Assignment1 ---
    [INFO] Tests are skipped.
    [INFO]
    [INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.4:jar (default-jar) @ Serenity_RestAssured_Assignment1 ---
    [WARNING] JAR will be empty - no content was marked for inclusion!
    [INFO] Building jar: 
    C:\ eclipse_workspace\Serenity_RestAssured_Assignment1\target\Serenity_RestAssured_Assignment1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Total time:  3.305 s
    [INFO] Finished at: 2022-06-24T04:14:55+05:30
```

It shows “tests are skipped” and “jar will be empty”.

My question is why `mvn verify`  is not running **MyIT.java** test despite that naming convention is proper for integration test(maven failsafe plugin). Maven surefire plugin is skipping the tests but maven failsafe plugin should identify the MyIT.java test.

EDIT: `mvn clean test-compile failsafe:integration-test` is able to run the MyIT.java test successfully but `mvn clean test-compile failsafe:verify` does not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is simply because you have defined the [maven-failsafe-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/usage.html) in pluginManagement only.

The usual way is to define the version in pluginManagement while the binding has to be done in build area.

```
  <build>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.0-M7</version>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>integration-test</goal>
              <goal>verify</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

I also recommend to upgrade your used plugins which means define newer versions of all used plugin in pluginManagement.

Furthermore you should not define a configuration for maven-surefire-plugin:

```
<configuration>
  <skip>true</skip>
</configuration>
```